# How to select the faces that have reversed normals?

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> doesn't work.
There is a solution ?

[image: mesh with reversed normals]

I want select this faces :
[image]

Here's my .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hi, if you want to provide .blend files, please use exclusively http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ . Your link doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2207" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2207/)

Comment: @MrZak - When I tried to download it with RMB, it offered me a .html file. I didn't try any further (e.g. renaming the downloaded file to .blend or something). Ideally we shouldn't provide links that don't work in other circumstances than the "normal" way. That's why blend-exchange is such a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna select only reversed faces, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> but in Edge select mode. It doesn't work in Face select mode, and if you use it in Vertex select mode, it will select too much.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to clean up the wrong normals? 
Go into edit-mode, select everything (a), and press ctrl+n. This will recalculate the normals.

Comment: Yes i want clean up the wrong normal. Ctrl+N don't work on this mesh. You can try with may .blend. I want select face that have reversed normals.

Comment: But why? ______